# Why am I getting an error when I am trying to change a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I am trying to change a tuple but, it keeps giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    my_tuple[1] = 'y'
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

My code is:

```
my_tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
my_tuple[1] = 'y'
print(my_tuple)
```

Comment: tuples are immutable !

Comment: Tuples in python are immutable. The values cannot be re-assigned like the way you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Tuples are not lists

In a list, you can write a new value to any element of the list.

In a tuple, you can't.

This property of tuples, "immutability", enables them to be used in different ways from lists, sometimes more efficiently.

Perhaps you would be better off with a list?

Answer (score 4):

**Tuples are immutable**, if you want to change you can convert to list then back to tuple:

```
my_tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
l=list(my_tuple)
l[1]='y'
my_tuple=tuple(l)

#(1, 'y', 3, 4, 5)
```

*Tuples are immutable ordered and indexed collections of objects. Tuples of two or more items are formed by comma-separated lists of expressions. A tuple of one item (a ‘singleton’) can be formed by affixing a comma to an expression (an expression by itself does not create a tuple, since parentheses must be usable for grouping of expressions). An empty tuple can be formed by an empty pair of parentheses.*

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/tuple/

Answer (score 1):

the tuples, while are faster than lists, cannot be modified.
It would be more convenient to transform it back to list, modify and set it back to tuple.

```
my_list=list(my_tuple)
my_list[1]='y'
my_tuple=tuple(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change an existing tuple. The only solution is to create a new tuple instance.

If that is acceptable you can do something like:

```py
my_tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
my_tuple = tuple('y' if i == 1 else x for i,x in enumerate(my_tuple))
print(my_tuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

its because tuples are constant, you can use list instead of tuples
like this

```
my_tuple = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_tuple[1] = 'y'
print(my_tuple)
```

you can check  this link for more information
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe change "constant" into "immutable".

Answer (score 0):

You can not change items in tuples in python, tuples are immutable.
If you want to change an item after you have made the variable you can better use a list like this:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_list[1] = 'y'
print(my_list)
```